# D700 clipping all my images

Tags: nikon-d700

I have had this D700 for 6 years.  Now it is clipping the top of all my images.  please see the image below

[image]

Comment: Is this consistent with every different lens that you have?

Comment: Do you hold the camera upside down when shooting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting... Try taking the lens off the body and taking a time exposure. Look into the camera body through the lens mount. See if the sensor is 'clear' with nothing projecting in front of it. Since the issue is at the top of the frame the blockage will be at the bottom of the sensor. I think the autofocus system is mounted in the bottom of the mirror box, and there may be something going on there... If you -do- see something, you can try to gently nudge it to see if it unsticks, but if it were mine I'd probably just send it back to Nikon for repairs.

Comment: OMG!  You are a genius!  I gently nudged the bottom of the mirror box and this piece in the shape of the clipping became unstuck.   The problem is resolved.  Thank you soon much!

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark my answer as the correct one...

Comment: I went to  use my D700 to take halloween pics and now it  doesn't autofocus   and in manual focus the shutter doesn't release consistently.  I tried different lenses with the same problem.  With the lens off the body, there isnt a problem with the shutter.

Comment: Time to send it in for repairs...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but my guess is that the mirror is not quite raising all the way. What else could it be?  You can remove the lens, and watch the mirror as you press the shutter button, and probably can see it not quite raising all the way.  Sounds like a repair is necessary.

Comment: The mirror is at the 'bottom' of the inverted image as it is projected onto the sensor. If the mirror were hanging down slightly it would cast a shadow at the bottom of the photo (unless the camera is being held upside down when the photo was taken). For something to shade the top of the photo it would be in the bottom of the light box when the camera is held upright.